# Langevin dynamics

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, machine-learning, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

From [this paper](https://francahoffmann.files.wordpress.com/2018/07/302ca7465ae824f3d2d629bfeaacfb56b4b8.pdf), if the deterministic dynamics of
$x_t$ is $dx_t=v_tdt$ where $v_t=\nabla\log\pi-\nabla\log\mu_t$ with $\mu_t$ denotes the law of $x_t$ and $\pi$ is a distribution depending on $x_t$, then the Langevin dynamic of $x_t$ is given by
$$
dx_t=\nabla\log\pi(x_t)dt+\sqrt{2}dB_t
$$
where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion.

**Question**: Assume that $g$ is a nice function. I would like to ask if the deterministic dynamics of $y_t$ is
$$dy_t=u_tdt, \quad u_t=g(y_t)[\nabla\log\pi(y_t)-\nabla\log\mu_t(y_t)]$$
then what is the corresponding Langevin dynamics of $y_t$.

Comment: If $\pi,\mu$ are known, then the difficulty is in solving this nonlinear ODE. There is no randomness involved in that case.

Comment: I'm a bit confused : how can $x_t$ have both deterministic and stochastic dynamics ? Where exactly in the paper is your claim stated ? As you've written, it seems like $x_t$ and $y_t$ are just solutions of some ODE, as stated above.